# How to allow client pass my object through webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, object, remoting

Sorry if this is stupid question, because I'm a bit confused about .NET remoting and distributed object.

I want to write a webservice, and in one of its methods, I want user to pass one my object's instance as parameter. It will greatly reduces number of parameters, and help user call this method more effectively. I create some class, but when distributing them to client, only class name remains, all properties and methods are gone, just like this

```
public class CameraPackages
{
    private readonly List<CameraPackage> _packages;

    public CameraPackages()
    {
        _packages = new List<CameraPackage>();
    }

    public void AddNewCamera(CameraPackage package)
    {
        _packages.Add(package);
    }

    public void RemoveCamera(CameraPackage package)
    {
        if(_packages.Contains(package))
            _packages.Remove(package);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}
```

into this: (in Reference.cs)

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/")]
public partial class CameraPackages {
}
```

How can I do to allow user use my object?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Web Services will only serialise public properties, so you can't do that (in that way) using web services.

You will need to manage your list of objects client side, then send the data in a transfer object (a class with just properties).

Have a [look at this](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020134052/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/100803-1.aspx).

Comment: Sorry, I assume this is a question about web services - not remoting, which is different. Have you considered using WCF? - your better off learning that, rather than these older technologies.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm planning to learn WCF, but not right now, when I have a deadline on next Monday